# Updating a JTextArea dynamically and reading specific text from it

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am building an ATM simulator with one JTextArea which will display all interaction with the user. I want the user to enter the pin and it shows him in the JtextArea asterisks below a welcome message. How would i display asterisks while reading them as real numbers in my code so that I can verify my user?. I also want the JTextArea to update dynamically with different text as the user goes from one step to the next.It would for example over write the text for entering the pin with text about withdrawal etc. It would continue doing so and user will see the screen updating with the relevant information. Any resources or help about how i can manipulate a JtextArea are welcome or if someone can suggest a better approach to achieve this.

Comment: How tied are you to the idea that all interaction is done using a single `JTextArea`?

Comment: @Greg I am open to suggestions of a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to use the JTextArea as if it were a console where it interacts with the user line by line, and doesn't display the PIN numbers, it may get a little tricky. One possible solution is to use a DocumentFilter on the JTextArea's Document (cast first to a PlainDocument) and pass through all text entered *unless* your program is in PIN acquisition mode (perhaps you'll have a boolean variable for this), and in that situation, you'd save the text entered to the program itself, but only display "*" via the DocumentFilter. This may be overkill, but it could work.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a instance a `JPasswordField` may be that you need.

For put asterisks,

```
passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
```

And for recover the PIN:

```
char[] pin = passwordField.getPassword();
```

With this aproach, you need some other components, like `JLabel` for show information to the user, a Welcome message.

Comment: That's a fine and workable solution if he isn't using JTextArea like a console. 1+

Comment: This doesn't address the "display all interaction with the user" aspect - but as Hovercraft Full Of Eels says, using a JTextArea to do this is "tricky".

Comment: @PaulVargas How would i manipulate the different elements in a single jframe.

Comment: You can start with [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) in [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)